# Spacing between 2 Rows in a HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that has some Fill in the blanks such as a form and I want to create a HTML Table that looks a lot like the real PDF File how do you create 2 Lines in `<td>` That look a lot like this:

[image: This Image]

Right now it looks like this in the page:

[image: This second]

Here is the Raw  HTML of how its done:

```html
    <table>
         <tr><td><font>Balance Forward: $1,000.00</font><br/>
    <font>______________________________________</font></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: are you familiar with `CSS` there are some pretty good samples and sites online that let you learn as well as edit realtime to see what the effects of editing css does

Comment: Yes Sir I have used CSS before but unfortunately where I work we are not allowed to make changes or add another CSS File to the Site so I have to work with the raw solution such as `Style` Tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use border :

```css
span {
  padding: 0 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Balance Forward: <span>$1,000.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or like this if you want to keep a table structure

```css
.border {
  padding: 0 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Balance Forward:
      </td>
    <td class="border">
      $1,000.00
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Balance Forward:
      </td>
    <td class="border">
      $10.00
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This helped for the page thanks! one issue tho when I send this in a Email as a Email body the Span some how does not show up any idea on that

Comment: @HaseebAhmad only span comes ? and the tables not ?

Comment: @HaseebAhmad and what about my second solution without span ?

Comment: Yes no Span And I cant have 2 Td's for styling perpose they have to stick with one TD only

Comment: @HaseebAhmad ok, so you can try to put inline style on the span like this `<span style="border-bottom:1px solid;padding:0 50px">$1,000.00</span>` in the mail

Comment: Got it Worked Thanks!

Comment: @HaseebAhmad great ;) for email purpose always use inline styles as this is how it works

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font>
                Balance Forward: <u> $1,000.00</u>
            </font>
            <br/>
        </td>
        </t>
</table>
```

Try the HTML u tag...

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: @HaseebAhmad sure. I have posted one more answer more specific to the HTML table you have... see that as well. If it helps....

Answer (score -1):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Balance Forward:
      </td>
    <td class="border">
      <u>$1,000.00</u>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Balance Forward:
      </td>
    <td class="border">
       <u>$10.00</u>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: don't post two answer, consider editing the first one to add more details

Comment: and what's the use of `class="border"` ? you may remove useless code when doing copy/paste